# How do I read an array of structs from a file and sort it?

Tags: c++, arrays, insertion-sort

Preface: Guidelines set by professor, I must use the array, not some other data structure. His psuedo code (which isn't very concise) of the method we should be following:

```
name and grade are read into a temporary location
loop from the end of the filled part of the array down to beginning {
if (new last name < current last name) {
   copy current name and grade down
}
else if (new/current last names are equal and new first name < current first name) {
   copy/assign current name and grade down
}
else {
   found right place, break out of loop
}
}
now that you've made room, insert (copy) new name into correct sorted position
```

I see that I'm probably breaking array bounds by attempting to read array position [-1] but I can't think of a way to avoid that since I'm counting backwards from the number of items I have and have to compare them.

I'm reading lines from a text file and storing pieces of each line into a struct. Then I'm using an insertion-sort-esque algorithm to store the structs in alphabetical order. However, my array does not seem to populate past the first couple lines with the new lines simply overwriting the previous lines... It's as if one of my comparison tests is failing since my copy position never appears to change although that could be because the initial array populating is failing in some way. I feel foolish, I must be missing something simple... Also my DisplayList module apparently never gets an array that's been populated with anything. Am I altering the array in an incorrect manner?

Here is the module with the problem:

```
bool sortInput(ifstream &infile, StudentType students[], int size)
{
   StudentType temp;
   int copyToHere;

   if(size == 0)
   {
      infile >> temp.last >> temp.first >> temp.grade;
      strcpy(students[0].last, temp.last);
      strcpy(students[0].first, temp.first);
      students[0].grade = temp.grade;
      size++;
   } 

   while(infile)
   {
      infile >> temp.last >> temp.first >> temp.grade;
      //cout << "TEST" << temp.last << temp.first << temp.grade << endl;

      for(int i = size; i > 0; i--)
      {       
         if(strcmp(temp.last, students[i-1].last) < 0)
         {
            students[i] = students[i-1];
            students[i-1] = temp;
         }
         else if(strcmp(temp.last, students[i].last) == 0 && strcmp(temp.first, students[i].first) < 0)
         {
            students[i] = students[i-1];
         }
         else
         {
            break;
         }

         copyToHere = i;
      }

      cout << "Size = " << size << " and copy position = " << copyToHere << endl;
      students[copyToHere] = temp;
      size++;

      //test to see if array is populated properly
      for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
         cout << "Name is " << students[i].first << " " << students[i].last << " and grade is " << students[i].grade << endl;
      }

      cout << "DONE" << endl;

   } //end while loop

   return true;
}
```

Here is the full code (if necessary for whatever reason or further context):

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// You write meaningful doxygen comments and assumptions

#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int const MAXSIZE = 100;            // maximum number of records in total
int const MAXLENGTH = 31;           // maximum string length 
int const MAXGRADE = 100;           // highest possible grade
int const LOWGRADE = 0;             // lowest possible grade
int const GROUP = 10;               // group amount
int const HISTOGRAMSIZE = (MAXGRADE-LOWGRADE)/GROUP + 1;    // grouped by GROUP

struct StudentType  {               // information of one student
   int grade;                       // the grade of the student
   char last[MAXLENGTH];            // last name (MAXLENGTH-1 at most)
   char first[MAXLENGTH];           // first name (MAXLENGTH-1 at most)
};

// prototypes go here
bool sortInput(ifstream &, StudentType [], int);
void displayList(StudentType [], int);
/*setHistrogram();
displayHistogram();
findAverage();*/

//------------------------------- main ----------------------------------------
int main()  {
   StudentType students[MAXSIZE];   // list of MAXSIZE number of students
   int size = 0;                    // total number of students
   int histogram[HISTOGRAMSIZE];    // grades grouped by GROUP
   int average = 0;                 // average exam score, truncated

   // creates file object and opens the data file
   ifstream infile("data1.txt");
   if (!infile)  { 
      cout << "File could not be opened." << endl; 
      return 1;  
   }

   // read and sort input by last then first name
   bool successfulRead = sortInput(infile, students, size);              

   // display list, histogram, and class average 
   if (successfulRead)  {
      displayList(students, size);
     // setHistogram(... you figure parameters ...);
     // displayHistogram(... you figure parameters ...);
     // average = findAverage(... you figure parameters ...);
      cout << "Average grade: " << average << endl << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}

bool sortInput(ifstream &infile, StudentType students[], int size)
{
   StudentType temp;
   int copyToHere;

   if(size == 0)
   {
      infile >> temp.last >> temp.first >> temp.grade;
      strcpy(students[0].last, temp.last);
      strcpy(students[0].first, temp.first);
      students[0].grade = temp.grade;
      size++;
   } 

   while(infile)
   {
      infile >> temp.last >> temp.first >> temp.grade;
      //cout << "TEST" << temp.last << temp.first << temp.grade << endl;

      for(int i = size; i > 0; i--)
      {       
         if(strcmp(temp.last, students[i-1].last) < 0)
         {
            students[i] = students[i-1];
            students[i-1] = temp;
         }
         else if(strcmp(temp.last, students[i].last) == 0 && strcmp(temp.first, students[i].first) < 0)
         {
            students[i] = students[i-1];
         }
         else
         {
            break;
         }

         copyToHere = i;
      }

      cout << "Size = " << size << " and copy position = " << copyToHere << endl;
      students[copyToHere] = temp;
      size++;

      //test to see if array is populated properly
      for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
         cout << "Name is " << students[i].first << " " << students[i].last << " and grade is " << students[i].grade << endl;
      }

      cout << "DONE" << endl;

   } //end while loop

   return true;
}

void displayList(StudentType students[], int size)
{
   cout << "List of names sorted:" << endl;

   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
      cout << " " << students[i].grade << " " << students[i].last << " " << students[i].first << endl;
   }
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// functions with meaningful doxygen comments and assumptions go here
```

Comment: Store them in a `std::list` and use `list::sort()` to sort them.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use an array (guideline set by professor).

Comment: You can still use `std::sort()` to sort your array. Or do you specifically have to implement an insertion sort?

Comment: Specifically have to implement an insertion sort while reading in each line. I added the psuedo-code he gave us to the question post though it isn't very clear. He makes it sounds like we need an indeterminate amount of temporary variables so I assumed he instead means to reassign every array position forwards to make space for the current read-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your insertion sort isn't really inserting properly. Let's look at one part of your main insertion loop:

```
   if(strcmp(temp.last, students[i-1].last) < 0)
     {
        students[i] = students[i-1];
        students[i-1] = temp;
     }
```

The intention of this is obviously to insert `temp` into the array at position `i-1`. You're shifting the item at `i-1` to `i` but what happened to the other elements in the array? You need to move them all up one position to make room for the inserted element. Something like:

```
memmove(students + i, students + i - 1, sizeof(students[0]) * size - i - 1);
```

You have other problems in your code too. `copyToHere` is potentially uninitialized. You are copying `temp` into the array multiple times (`students[i-1] = temp;` and `students[copyToHere] = temp;` aren't both needed). Once you have done the insertion in the inner loop you should break out. Your special handling for when the list is empty isn't really necessary, and so on.

Have a look at the [pseudo-code for an insertion sort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Algorithm) and see if you can simplify and rewrite yours to eliminate the problems.

Comment: Cheers think I figured out a solution. The idea behind that if statement is that since I'm starting from the end of my current list of items then it will shift every item that needs to be shifted to make room for the current temporary item.

I realized the else statement is where the actual insertion should be and that's why I break because at that point I've stored temp where it should go. I posted my new code down below as an answer if you wanted to critique but it appears to be working properly as the array populates with all names (though it doubles the last name).

Comment: One problem though that I haven't resolved is that my array doesn't pass to my other modules properly populated... it seems to only populate within that sorting module. Any ideas for that?

Comment: You're passing the array by value, which means each function will get passed a copy of it rather than the original. Change your function definitions to `StudentType students[]&` to pass by reference.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `StudentType (&students)[MAXSIZE]`.

Comment: Is that only for the function definitions or do I need to also modify the call itself and the prototypes to reflect this?

Comment: The way you call it won't change.

Comment: Changed the definitions to your suggestion and the prototypes similarly:

bool sortInput(ifstream &, StudentType (&students)[MAXSIZE], int); and it compiles without any errors but still the DisplayList module doesn't seem to receive a modified array.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to my own problem haha. I was stupid for not having completed the else statement properly. Now I'm working to redo my first name comparisons as something appears wrong since it wont order same last names alphabetically.

LESSON LEARNED: Get it all down before thinking you're forked. Now I really do feel like an idiot, hopefully didn't waste many peeps time.

```
  for(int i = size; i > 0; i--)
  {       
     if(strcmp(temp.last, students[i-1].last) < 0)
     {
        students[i] = students[i-1];
        students[i-1] = temp;
     }
     else if(strcmp(temp.last, students[i].last) == 0 && strcmp(temp.first, students[i].first) < 0)
     {
        students[i] = students[i-1];
        students[i-1] = temp;
     }
     else
     {
        students[i] = temp;
        break;
     }

     insertHere = i;
  }
```